# Material UI Slider - Label Formating

Tags: reactjs, slider, material-ui, material-design

I have the following Range Slider which displays values from 1000 to 1,000,000.

[image]

I want to display the label is a more readable format such as `100k` `1M` `1k` etc. Is it possible to format the label inside the tooltip so it makes more sense for the user and does not break the UX.

I want to use this function to change the way the number is show.

```
function numFormatter(num) {
    if(num > 999 && num < 1000000){
        return (num/1000).toFixed(0) + 'K'; // convert to K for number from > 1000 < 1 million 
    }else if(num > 1000000){
        return (num/1000000).toFixed(0) + 'M'; // convert to M for number from > 1 million 
    }else if(num < 900){
        return num; // if value < 1000, nothing to do
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Material-UI Slider has props named **valueLabelFormat**

> The format function the value label's value.

Refer:

- MUI Slider [Props API document](https://material-ui.com/api/slider/)
- Source of props type definition: [Slider.d.ts](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Slider/Slider.d.ts)

```
valueLabelFormat?: string | ((value: number, index: number) => React.ReactNode);
```

---

Usage sample:

```
valueLabelFormat={value => <div>{numFormatter(value)}</div>}
```

Screenshot:

[image]